# Where do I ask question, which specifies an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion

Suppose there is situation:

User1 asked question1.
User2 answered it nicely, but not 100.000% fully.
User1 accepted answer of User2.
User3 comes and want to ask very specific and hard question2, which is part of question1.

1. Where should user3 ask question, which specifies an accepted answer? In comments to answer1 or as a new question?

   1. If he makes a new question this would be a doublicate, that is probably bad for community.
   2. If he asks it in comments, only User2 and moderators will see it and will be able to answer it, and they got only one chance, ones they read a comment it will be lost between all other information. That is even worse for user, whose chances to get an answer decreases by orders of magnitudes. Plus he would be able to describe it nicely, with pictures, formatting etc.
2. What if user3 has < 50 reputations and can't leave comments? Must he wait until he collects reputation?

Answer (score 7):

If someone has a new question, even if it is a follow on question of an existing question (with an accepted answer or without), they should ask a new question.

In the new question, they can link to the original question, explaining where they are coming from and giving the needed background. It is not difficult to ask the same question but refocus it towards the specific "hard question" part.

This has value.

I don't see how such a question would be a duplicate, as by definition it is a different question - a more narrowly focused one.

---

As for follow on questions in comments - if the user doesn't have 50 rep then yes, they will have to wait till they do.

Comment: Ok. Here is an example I just saw on gamingSE: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174218/what-do-these-three-symbols-on-antichambers-map-mean . 5 people voted to close this more narrowly focused and differently formulated question. Were they wrong? If yes, what can be done about it?

Comment: @klm123 - I don't know enough about the game to tell whether it _is_ any different. But in this case - I would say that asking to expand on the answer would be the right move. The question is not a focus on something different or actually requires a different answer - just a **slightly** expanded one. That would be different from asking for a strategy based on specific map situation (to give an example borrowed from your example).

Comment: I figured this might be about the Arqade question.  It's a bit of an inconsistency for us; sometimes we dupe, sometimes we leave it alone.  Much of the judgement is how big a change it really is; it's subjective, so sometimes it gets closed, and sometimes it doesn't.